# After removing welcome-content handler I am getting 404 not found error in jboss eap 7.1

Tags: jboss

I want to land on directly log in page of JBOSS hence I removed the handler and now I am getting '`404 not found error`' on running jboss application. Can anyone please help.

```
/subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/file=welcome-content:remove

/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/host=default-host/location="/":remove
```

ran above two commands.

Comment: You do not need to remove anything. You can use http://<server-ip>:9990/console/index.html to access jboss console directly

Comment: Yes ,but want to remove the welcome content and directly log on to log in page when I enter http://<server-ip>:8080

Comment: Can you please let me know hwo can I accomplish this? and why am I getting 404 not found error

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `404 not found error` because you removed welcome content from your configuration.

Add all the removed configuration again and try to access the admin console using

```
http://<server-ip>:9990/console/index.html
```

you should be able to access jboss admin console.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I add it back?

Comment: /subsystem=undertow/configuration=handler/file=new-file-handler:add(path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content")    is this ok to add

Comment: looks ok. Same way you have to add other property as well